# How to autofill a radio_button, a few combo_boxes, many text_boxes, and a calendar FROM a combo_box selection

Tags: c#

I am creating a tool that will allow a Human Resource employee to input various information about a new employee into an access database(for academic purposes). So far I have the layout set-up (as you will be able to see shortly), validation is in a place, and a dataGridView gets populated by using an Access Database I created. Then I have 3 buttons, Submit (Insert), Update and Delete.

PS: I know that the table I am trying to update is huge, but that's what our team decided to do.

Image of my layout:

[Human Resource employee tool](http://postimage.org/image/m5ba7b5vj/full/)

The submit and delete works, BUT the update only works if all of the fields are filled with data. The code I wrote tries to update all the fields WHERE the EMPLOYEE_ID equals the value that's selected on the combo_box, so if I try to update only one field I get an error saying "No value given for one or more required parameters". I think that by auto-filling all the field on the left when a value from a combo_box is selected will fix my problem. The thing is that I have no idea on how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciate it!!

UPDATE STATEMENT.

```
private void cmdModify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Setting up Connection String
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

            string SqlString = "UPDATE Employee SET FIRST_NAME = @FirstName , LAST_NAME= @LastName, MIDDLE_NAME = @MiddleName, DATE_HIRED =@DateHired, WAGE_TYPE =@WageType, WAGE = @Wage, GENDER =@Gender, MARTIAL_STATUS =@MartialStatus, UNIT_NUMBER =@UnitNumber, STREET_NUMBER =@StreetNumber, STREET_NAME =@StreetName, CITY =@City, PROVINCE =@Province, POSTAL_CODE =@PostalCode, HOME_NUMBER =@HomeNumber, CELL_NUMBER =@CellNumber, JOB_TITTLE =@JobTittle, END_DATE=7/24/2013, DPT_NAME =@Department, NOTES =@Notes WHERE [EMPLOYEE_ID] = @EMPLOYEE_ID";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", txtMname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateHired", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WageType", cmbType.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Wage", txtWage.Text);
                    if (rbMale.Checked == true)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", rbMale.Text);
                    }
                    else if (rbFemale.Checked == true)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", rbFemale.Text);
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MartialStatus", cmbStatus.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UnitNumber", txtUnit.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StreetNumber", txtStreetNo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StreetName", txtStreet.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", txtCity.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Province", cmbState.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PostalCode", txtPostal.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HomeNumber", txtHphone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CellNumber", txtCphone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobTittle", cmbJobTitle.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", cmbDepartment.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Notes", txtNotes.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPLOYEE_ID", comboBox1.SelectedValue);

                    try
                    {
                        // openning a connection to the database / table
                        conn.Open();
                        // SQL commnd class
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //Closing Database connection
                        conn.Close();
                        //Console.WriteLine("Data was added to the table !!!");
                        MessageBox.Show("Data was added to the table !!!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // printing exception message to default output
                    }
                }
            }
            Refresh();
            clearText();
        }
```

INSERT STATEMENT.

```
private void Insert_Data()
        {
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            string SqlString = "INSERT INTO Employee (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, DATE_HIRED, WAGE_TYPE, WAGE, GENDER, MARTIAL_STATUS,UNIT_NUMBER, STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME, CITY ,PROVINCE, POSTAL_CODE, HOME_NUMBER, CELL_NUMBER, JOB_TITTLE, END_DATE, DPT_NAME, NOTES) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@MiddleName,@DateHired,@WageType,@Wage,@Gender,@MartialStatus,@UnitNumber,@StreetNumber,@StreetName,@City,@Province,@PostalCode,@HomeNumber,@CellNumber,@JobTittle,7/24/2013,@Department,@Notes)";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MiddleName", txtMname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateHired", dateTimePicker1.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("WageType", cmbType.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Wage", txtWage.Text);
                    if (rbMale.Checked == true)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender",rbMale.Text);
                    }
                    else if (rbFemale.Checked == true)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Gender", rbFemale.Text);
                    }
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MartialStatus", cmbStatus.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UnitNumber", txtUnit.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StreetNumber", txtStreetNo.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("StreetName", txtStreet.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", txtCity.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Province", cmbState.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PostalCode", txtPostal.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HomeNumber", txtHphone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CellNumber", txtCphone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobTittle", cmbJobTitle.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", cmbDepartment.SelectedItem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Notes", txtNotes.Text);

                    try
                    {
                        // openning a connection to the database / table
                        conn.Open();
                        // SQL commnd class
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //Closing Database connection
                        conn.Close();
                        //Console.WriteLine("Data was added to the table !!!");
                        MessageBox.Show("Data was added to the table !!!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // printing exception message to default output
                    }
                }
            }
            Refresh();
            clearText();
        }
```

DELETE STATEMENT

```
private void cmdDelete_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Setting up Connection String
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            string SqlString = "DELETE * FROM Employee WHERE [EMPLOYEE_ID] = @EMPLOYEE_ID ";

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPLOYEE_ID", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
                    try
                    {
                        // openning a connection to the database / table
                        conn.Open();
                        // SQL commnd class
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //Closing Database connection
                        conn.Close();
                        //Console.WriteLine("Data was added to the table !!!");
                        MessageBox.Show("Data was deleted from the table !!!");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); // printing exception message to default output
                    }
                }
            }
            Refresh();
            clearText();
        }
```

Comment: Why have the combo boxes at all, why not just allow the grid selection to decide. Then you can delete from the grid, and when the grid selection changes you can populate the data controls on the left from the row selected in the grid. Then the submit can do double duty, if the data came from the grid do an update, if the data is new then do insert. If all data needs to be entered you can add a validation pass that ensures all data has been provided. The two combos on the bottom with update/delete buttons just clutter the UI and provide no value.

Comment: What's the grid selection, and how exactly (in code) do I get to do what you described? I thought that having different buttons and combo_boxes was more intuitive. :S

Comment: The grid selection would be the selection that has been made in the data grid you have in your form. I was assuming that since in the screenshot there was a selection, that the grid is selectable. Use the selection there to populate the controls on the right. All of the values you need are in the grid so you won't need to make another trip to the DB just to populate those fields. As far as how to do it, add a handler for the selection event, push the data into your controls in the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the AddWithValue method is adding null to the Parameters collection. What you need is for it to add DBNull instead.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFname.Text ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Those SelectedItem values might cause you problems too if they are complex types:

> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Province", cmbState.SelectedItem);

You might have to specify a property on the instance to make it work

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Province", cmbState.SelectedItem.MyIdProperty);
```